# Rotate any GameObject between Two Angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

My question is fairly simple and I have come up with a solution but cannot seem to get the basic requirement done, basically I want an object to rotate between two angles, for example if the gameobject in question is at 0 degrees in y, then it should first rotate y to 45 degree; and after that it should rotate to -45 degrees, thus continuously alternating between these two angles.

The solution which I came up with was to use Mathf.Sin function to alternate between the angles since the angle is common i.e 45 I will use the positive max and negative max of sine wave to achieve this, but can't seem to get it work. The code in Update is as follows:

```
Vector3 startPos = transform.position; // umm, start position !
        Vector3 targetPos = Vector3.zero; // variable for calculated end position

        float startAngle = -theAngle * 0.5f; // half the angle to the Left of the forward
        float finishAngle = theAngle * 0.5f; // half the angle to the Right of the forward

        // the gap between each ray (increment)
        float inc = (theAngle / segment);

        RaycastHit hit;



            // linecast between points
        if ( Physics.Linecast( startPos, targetPos, out hit ) )
        {
            Debug.Log( "Hit " + hit.collider.gameObject.name );
        }    
        // to show ray just for testing
        Debug.DrawLine( startPos, targetPos, Color.green )
```

Comment: Sadly, I've answered this before. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: where is your rotation set?